# tinymce_hammer in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, spell-checking

How to use spell checker in tinymce_hammer in rails 3. Can anyone help me on this? Is there any method to use spell checker with tinymce hammer? this is a new concept and i dont know how to use spell checker with it

Comment: please post your tinymce config

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible setting the init param gecko_spellcheck to true:

```
gecko_spellcheck: true,
```

Comment: Is this for tinymce_hammer? if not, how to use spell check for tinymce_hammer.

Comment: there has to be a way to define the config settings, but i am sure the format of this setting in rails will look similar but diffrent from what i posted